# EF core migrating models in plugin libraries with a single DBContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to build a simplified module system for an application. At the moment I am trying out how to migrate data models by scanning assemblies in my modules. My project structure is as below

- ABC.Core - All interfaces and common models & builders (Such as ASP.Net Identity related models). The DbContext is also in this project
- ABC.Host - The host a web project which references core & plugins will be copied to /plugin directory.
- ABC.ModuleA/B/C - each module will have it's own Models, ModelBuilders, Controllers etc..

In the CORE project DBContext I scan for models and do the migration which works fine. It creates the common models that is needed by all modules (like ASP.Net Identity derived models & few others)

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.ApplyAllConfigurationsFromCurrentAssembly(GetType().Assembly, currentTenant);
    }
```

Next update I want to do is to scan plugins in /plugin directory in HOST project and call for modelbuilder's Configure methods (Each plugin has IEntityTypeConfiguration model builders).

So basically I changed the onModelCreating method in CORE DBContext to get the dlls, do some reflection and call IEntityTypeConfiguration.Configure methods. It throws below exception.

```
The shared-type entity type 'ABC.Core.Entities.Authentication.ApplicationRole'cannot be added because the model already contains an entity type with the same name, but with a different CLR type 'ApplicationRole'. Ensure all entity type names are unique.
```

I made sure I don't have another ApplicationRole mistakenly placed even in another namespace. Only thing I can suspect is that my Host & Module projects all has a reference to ABC.Core project. Can this be a reason?

What would be a good way to do this kind of migrations for a plugin based project? Requirement is when you execute add-migration / update-database, it should scan assemblies and create the migration script (Even though models are separated, there will be one migration script). I don't want to have separate DBContexts for each plugin. I think through reflection we should be able to do the migration and also attach the models in plugins at runtime so the entire application can run through single Context.

Comment: Through this step, the error can not be produced, can you share some other necessary codes?

Comment: Found a solution at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLomPArAt60 It has lot more than what I needed, but the concept wise I have what's needed.

Comment: hello @user2058413 i am trying to do the same, do you have a minimal project for the same.. the project explained in video is too big and with bad english for just a single concept